# Приложение на Angular не получается ответ от сервера

Tags: java, spring, angular

Имеется приложение на Angular, в роли backend выступает приложение на Java-Spring.
Оба они запущенны на сервере в общей сети, на машине с OC Windows в VirtualBox (Linux).
Суть проблемы в том, что при попытке открыть веб-приложение в браузере оно полностью запускается на одном компьютере из пяти с OC Windows и на одном из одного на OC Linux.
Браузер везде Chrom, только в Linux Mozilla
Само приложение запускается, но оно при запуске не получается данные от backend.
При этом получаю ошибку

```
Failed to load resource:
http://10.151.78.6:5003/es-serv/api/v1/get-data/sh1 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Вот метод контроллера, который получает запросы, в логах нет его вызова

```
   @GetMapping("/get-data/" + RestApiConstants.VARIABLE_NAME)
    public ResponseEntity<ListResponse<DataDto>> getData(
       @PathVariable(RestApiConstants.PARAM_NAME_WORD) String name) {
        log.info("getData -> start");
        return converterDtoService.converterDataDto(name);
    }
```

Причем, если в строке браузера просто попробовать открыть ссылку

```
http://10.151.78.6:5003/es-serv/api/v1/get-data/sh1
```

То данные получаю каждый раз, сбоев не разу не заметил.
Очень похоже на проблему с CORS, но тогда браузер выдает конкретную ошибку на все запросы. Да и в Java-приложение отключен cors. Да и тогда не понятно, почему на некоторых браузерах оно все-таки работает.
На проблему с тайм-аутом тоже не похоже, т.к. ошибку получаю мгновенно, а когда сервер не отвечает, то проходит какое-то время и это заметно.
И еще такой момент, в приложение добавил кнопку принудительного чтения данных. И вот через 20-30 попыток чтения данных ответ может все-таки прийти тех компьютерах которые их не получали.

Если бы это была проблема с сетью, тогда непонятно почему на там же компьютере из того же браузера GET запрос набранный в строке браузера получает все время получает ответы, без единого пропуска.

Подскажите куда смотреть, чтобы понять в чем причина?

Comment: Чтобы проверить на CORS нужно посмотреть, что в консоли браузера или на вкладке network в dev-tools хрома или другого браузера. Добавьте их, чтобы было больше понимания контекста. Возможно проблема в сетевом подключении.

Comment: Ошибку которую я привел в вопросе, это и есть из консоли браузера. Если бы это была проблема с CORS , то она должна была бы проявится и просто из строки браузера

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена обновлением браузеров на последнюю версии. Причем до этого версия браузера была не очень старая. Я не понимаю как это могло повлиять на передачу GET запроса по сети?

Comment: Я сам только изучаю Angular и у меня тоже была аналогичная проблема. Я тоже не понимаю как могло обновление браузера исправить такую ошибку, хотя на другой машине даже с более старой версией браузера оно прекрасно работало.